# jQuery and others js src is not defined when use div.load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

When loading a page with **jQuery load**:

```
$("#myDiv").load("page.php",{foo: bar});
```

head included in the **index**:

```
<head>
    <script src="/assets/plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/plugins/jquery-print/jquery.print.js" ></script>
    \\others js src
</head>
```

Not found on this div the content is **page.php**:

```
<div id="myDiv">
    \\if i call $("#otherDiv").print()  
</div>
```

.print() function not exists, that is already included in the index head

**Any idea, to this div view includes in head index?**

Comment: is there another version of jQuery included in the page

Comment: add script include in page.php or create function and run them after .load on index

Comment: There are just one jQuery version in my includes -> Arun

Comment: I have included a head.php an example with all js src, styles, js functions, but still does not work. -> wit_peter

Comment: Check the path of your `jquery.print.js` if it's correct. The problem might be caused by a 404 error on that file.

Comment: Open developer tools network tab in Chrome and make sure all your resources are loading properly.

Comment: Tks. The problem solved below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> \if i call $("#otherDiv").print()

Does `#otherDiv` exist in `document` when `.print()` is called ? `jQuery()` returns an object even where no element is found in `document`. The error message you are receiving could be that `.print()` is not a function of an element that does not exist in `DOM` ?

If `.load()` is successfully sets `#myDiv` `html` to `#otherDiv`, try using `.load()` callback function to call `.print()` when element exists in `document`

```
$("#myDiv").load("page.php", {foo: bar}, function() {
  $("#otherDiv").print();
});
```

Comment: Sucess, now I understand the concept.